# Wordpress - Show Portfolio Categories

Tags: categories, wordpress

I'm working with a WordPress website and a client wants to show a list of categories in the footer. Unfortunately, it is showing as empty because he has no posts and has set the categories to portfolio items which he wants people to be able to click to.

So, how do I show the portfolio categories in the widget rather than the post categories?

Thanks,

Jack

Comment: How is 'portfolio categories' defined? Are they custom post-type's, tags, or what? A bit of your code would be helpfull...

Comment: Well, I wouldn't want to put a load of random code up. If I knew which section to change I wouldn't have posted the question, the WordPress theme (New Horizon) supports portfolio entries like other themes and the categories have been defined through that sub-menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the easiest way I can think of to get the result that you want without having to resort to changing any Theme Files would be this:

1. Log into your Wordpress Dashboard
2. Navigate to Appearance->Menus
3. Create a new Menu, and (if applicable) enable the Custom Taxonomies for your menu by clicking on Screen Options (top right-hand corner of the page) and ticking your Portfolio's Custom Categories and/or Custom Post Types
4. Once all of the items you want is in your Custom Menu, save it.
5. Navigate to Appearance->Widgets
6. Add the Custom Menu Widget to the sidebar in which you would like your items to appear
7. Select the Custom Menu you just created, and Save

When dealing with Premium Themes, it would always be safest to stay out of their code and avoid changing anything altogether, so try this approach first. Otherwise, you may have to get your hands dirty and alter some code or contact the Theme Developer.

Comment: If this is the answer you where searching for, perfect. If you want to do it hardcorde coding, please let me know

Comment: Fantastic, this worked a treat. Thanks a lot! @DennisHunink thanks for the offer but a custom workaround like this is preferable to hard-coding in this case :)

Comment: It mostly is, depending on your demands. But glad it workout, good luck with it!